# Menu Bar with html/css

Tags: html, css

I want to make an horizontal bar with a list and research bar, both separated by a margin (I just don't want them to next to each other). I want all the bar to be of a color (in my example it is blue but I don't care it is just to try). However, when I try to put a margin or padding the color vanishes. I m pretty sure it is not the right way to do it. If someone could also tell me how to get rid of the small white layer above the bar that d be great. I want the color to start at the very top of the page.

Thank you for you help (I know I m bad at coding).

Here is the code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        #bar {
            background-color: blue;
        }
        #menu ul li {
            display: inline;
            float: left;
        }
        #form {
            padding-left: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="bar">

        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li id="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Archives</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Followers</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Support</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="form">
            <form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/custom">
                <input name="q" size="25" maxlength="255" value="" type="text" />
                <input name="sa" value="search" type="submit" />
                <input name="cof" value="" type="hidden" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6dwwy/ is this what you want?

Comment: Well, I want the search box to be placed on the same line than the list

Comment: Sorry my bad, it s fine. But do you have an idea to make the bar start at the very top of the page. Right now I still have a tiny white layer above the bar.

Comment: Did you check that the body or html doesn't have padding in the user-agent styles? Or explicitly set: html, body { margin:0, padding:0}

Comment: You could try using Boostrap

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/U9aS5/6/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#bar {
    background-color: blue;
}
#menu ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
a {
    color: white;
}

#form {
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li id="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Archives</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Profile</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Followers</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Support</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="form">
        <form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/custom">
            <input name="q" size="25" maxlength="255" value="" type="text" />
            <input name="sa" value="search" type="submit" />
            <input name="cof" value="" type="hidden" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

To remove "extra white space on top of the page" you can use css global selector `*` and set `padding` and `margin` to 0([reset all margins and padding](http://css-tricks.com/reset-all-margins-padding/)).

Answer (score 0):

In your code proper use of float and clearing the float is missing. This might help you:

```
#bar {background: red; width: 100%;}
#menu {float: left;}
#menu ul {list-style-type:none;}
#menu li {display: inline-block;}

#form {float: right;}

.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eHnn5/9/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ujfLc/

===== **HTML** =====

```
<div id="bar" class="clearfix">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li id="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Archives</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Followers</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Support</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="form">
        <form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/custom">
            <input name="q" size="25" maxlength="255" value="" type="text" />
            <input name="sa" value="search" type="submit" />
            <input name="cof" value="" type="hidden" />
        </form>
    </div>   
</div>
```

===== **CSS** =====

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
 }

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}

#bar {
    background-color: black;
    padding: 10px;
}

#menu {
    float: left;
}

#menu ul {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#menu ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float:left;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

#menu ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#form {
    float:right;
    padding-left: 30px;

}
```

===== **SCREENSHOT** =====

[image]

Answer (score 0):

u might want to use the reset.css to get rid of the white spaces... you can search the internet for the file or just copy these codes..

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
display: block;
}
body {
line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
content: '';
content: none;
}
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bar needs to clear:both so the links gives it the proper height and you should see the background color